# Three equal weights A, B and C of mass 2kg each are hanging on an ideal string passing over an ideal pulley.

Tags: physics, constraints

The tension in the string between B and C is?[image]

Let’s consider B and C as one unit of mass 4kg. The tension on both sides of the string will be T. Also assume that the the acceleration is upwards for A and downwards for B and C. Let g=10

The the equations shall be

For A
$$T-20=2a$$
And for B and C
$$40-T=4a$$

Solving these we get the a=30. You may have realized by now that I have done something wrong, but I haven’t yet. The right answer is 13N. How should I solve it?

EDIT:

The tension on the string for A will be T, but the downward force due to gravity will be 2(10)=20N

So net force is $F=T-20=(2)(a)$

Comment: I’m sure someone on this site can answer this question, but it would probably be more appropriate on the physics site.

Comment: I tried, but the physics site is just terrible. They refuse to answer any question that doesn’t meet their ‘elite’ standards and asked me to post in on math instead,

Comment: Added that in the edit

Comment: It's a mistake to consider $B$ and $C$ as one weight.

Comment: @Vasya:  that is fine as we don't ask about the tension in the rope between them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote $T_{AB}$ to be the tension in the rope $AB$ and $T=T_{BC}$.

Then from kinematics, we know that accelerations of bodies are $a_A=a$, $a_B=a_C=-a$ (axis goes upwards). Newton's law for 3 bodies:

$$
ma = T_{AB} - mg,\qquad (A)\\
m(-a) = T_{AB}-T_{BC}-mg,\qquad(B)\\
m(-a) = T_{BC}-mg.\qquad(C)
$$

We have 3 equations and 3 unknowns ($a$, $T_{AB}$, $T_{BC}$). We substract $(A)$ from $(B)$:
$$
-ma-ma = -T_{BC},\qquad ma = \frac12 T_{BC}.\qquad (*)
$$

Then we add $(C)$ and $(*)$:
$$
ma - ma = \frac12T_{BC} + T_{BC}-mg, \qquad T_{BC}=\frac23mg.
$$

If we let $g=10~\mathrm{m^2/s}$, then $T_{BC}=\frac23\times2\,\mathrm{kg}\times10~\mathrm{m^2/s}=13.3~\mathrm N$.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the two equations you get $$20=6a\\ a=\frac {20}6\\ T=\frac 23\cdot 20=\frac {40}3N$$  This is not $13$, but close.

Comment: It’s funny how one may have literally solved thousands of linear equations, and yet for some reasons keeps trying to subtract the equations rather than adding them for 3 pages. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Okay, why is $T=\frac 23 . 20$? If the equation is $T-20=2a$ , then it should be $T=20+\frac{20}{3}$